# I need Windows CMD to loop through folders in a directory and execute a command to convert webp to png on each one

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, png, webp

I have always use this command line to convert .webp to .png:

```
for %f in (*.webp) do dwebp.exe  "%f" -o "%~nf.png"
```

Works like a charm for single folders, but now I have several .webp files that I need to convert inside several folders in the same directory, example:

```
"C:\IMG\randomname"
"C:\IMG\randomname1"
"C:\IMG\randomname2"
```

And so on... I need help on how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Add `/R` **R**ecurse, *[loop through files (Recurse subfolders):](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)*

**2.** Replace output `-o "%~nf.png"` file to `-o "%~dpnf.png"`

---

```
for /R %f in (*.webp) do dwebp.exe  "%f" -o "%~dpnf.png"
```

- Or...

```
for /R "C:\IMG" %f in (*.webp) do dwebp.exe  "%f" -o "%~dpnf.png"
```

Read more  **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)** and **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**